# How to give custom package name for an item, of a style in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Documentation says, The name of the style property to be defined, with a package prefix if necessary (for example android:textColor).

```
 <style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
```

But i have a custom style in attrs.xml

```
  <attr name="switchStyle1" format="reference" />
    <declare-styleable name="Switch">
  </declare-styleable>
```

Now how do I use it in my custom style

```
 <style name="AppThemeDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <item name=":switchStyle">@style/switch_dark</item>
    </style>
```

How to give custom package name for an item, of a style in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not. The prefix (properly should be called namespace) is what you set yourself, by adding to i.e. your layout:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

In the above example `app` is your namespace. Then you use it in layouts i.e.

```
<Foo app:switchStyle="@style/switch_dark" />
```

In case of styles, you do not use the namespace at all, when referring to custom attributes:

```
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
   <item name="switchStyle">@style/switch_dark</item>
</style>
```

and since the namespace is global for all your libraries in project, it's important to make the name unique to avoid clash with other libraries (that's why most of them prefix attribute names, i.e:

```
<attr name="abc_switchStyle" format="reference" />
  ...
```

and use:

```
<Foo app:abc_switchStyle="@style/switch_dark" />
```

PS: in your code you create `switchStyle1` attribute, but reference `switchStyle`.

Comment: And by the way, may I know what is meant by format="reference" ?

Comment: it means that value can be given as reference to other value. i.e. `color` can be RGB or as reference, specified as `@color/xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Just use it this way:

```
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="switchStyle1">@style/switch_dark</item>
</style>
```

There is **no need** to use any package prefix if you use your style attributes